# Path de arquivo (Java Web)

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Tou trabalhando em um projeto web e tou tendo um problema com arquivos(`java.io.File`). O problema é somente quando estou rodando a aplicação web, se for `Java Application` o problema não existe.

Ao instanciar um arquivo, `new File("diretorio");`, o path dele fica `C://Windows/System32/diretorio`, sendo assim, não consigo fazer nada, talvez por não ter privilégios do Windows.

"Resolvi o problema" passando `new File("C://Users/myName/diretorio")`, mas não gostei da solução, queria fazer automático, pegar o path da própria aplicação, por exemplo, já que estou desenvolvendo na minha máquina e depois do deploy, como que fica... não sei.

Alguma dica?

Segue a parte do projeto que estou tendo o problema, um bean jsf.
Minha visão chama o método `addFile()` pra poder salvar o arquivo que eu recebo da visão. Está tudo funcional, mas tenho que passar o path da forma como falei anteriormente, da forma que está no código abaixo, o path fica pra pasta System32 do Windows.

**Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    //ATRIBUTOS E LÓGICAS DE NEGÓCIO

    public void addFile() {

        File temporario = new File("temporario");
        //LÓGICA DE NEGÓCIO

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso resolve o problema.
`File myTempFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),"temporary");`
Serve exatamente para um file temporário.